# RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: GUILDS

Tags: javascript, discord.js, chatbot, bit-fields

I'm new to programming and I'm currently stuck at this error on replit.com, I'm making a simple discord bot for our school

Here is the actual code that I'm writing along with the error message

[image: 1]

```
    const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log('Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!')
})

client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.content === "ping") {
    message.channel.send("pong")
  }
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

Here is the error message:

> RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: GUILDS.
> at Function.resolve (/home/runner/AnAbomination/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:168:11)
> at /home/runner/AnAbomination/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:163:54
> at Array.map ()
> at Function.resolve (/home/runner/AnAbomination/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:163:40)
> at Client._validateOptions (/home/runner/AnAbomination/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:482:41)
> at new Client (/home/runner/AnAbomination/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:78:10)
> at Object. (/home/runner/AnAbomination/index.js:2:16)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)

Comment: What version of `discord.js` are you using?

Comment: @新Acesyyy 14.1.2 po

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I'll try using their advice, thank you

Comment: Pretty sure @ZsoltMeszaros answered your problem.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros my code now looks like this: 
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
  ]
})

But the only error left is ReferenceError: Discord is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/AnAbomination/index.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
I think we're close to solving this error =>

Comment: @新Acesyyy Yup, but I still appreciate your help though

Comment: @AeonBoi `new Discord.Client` should be `new Client` only

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Whooops, my apologies. I fixed it now and it's all working nice and smooth. Thank you again for helping me go through this problem! This is my first day on this site and I'm very happy that you guys didn't grill me alive haha. cheers